# How to add a property to an element method?

Tags: javascript

The code looks like `document.getElementById.a = 1`. This works except in IE. As the document says

> the function is also an object

so it can be added properties, right?

Comment: post your code. I'll be helpful to find the problem

Comment: @fancy What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Yes.Function are objects and you can do that, but why?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can set or get properties on any value **unless**:

- it is `null` or `undefined`
- it has been [frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) or [sealed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)

It is usually bad practice to add properties to native objects/methods because doing so may conflict with other code on the page. I imagine there is a better way to do whatever you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

Try by using method `setAttribute` i.e.

```
document.getElementById('<IDofElement>').setAttribute('a',1);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add 'a' to Function prototype. Then it will be available for all Functions.

```
Function.prototype.a = 1;
console.log(document.getElementById.a); //logs 1
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName.a); //also logs 1
```

This is not the best solution, but should work even on IE.

Comment: Please **never** do this. Adding props to native prototypes is very bad practice. If you do it then that prop will be enumerated anytime *any* function is iterated via for/in and thus it has potential to cause problems in your code and any other code on the page.